# Can an evaded cadence end the antecedent of a period?

Tags: musical-forms, cadence

I would especially like an answer in the context of the theory of formal functions, although input from other perspectives is also welcomed.

The question arised when I was analyzing the main theme (or main themes?) of the first movement of the Piano Sonata nº 7 in C, k. by Mozart. In measures 7-8 we have a root position dominant moving to a root position tonic in a way that sounds to me as a cadential evasion, due to sudden change in dynamics, register and texture.
[image]
What follows is a restatement of the 4 opening measures which, after a greatly extended continuation, lead to a perfect authentic cadence in m. 21. As an evaded cadence is weaker than a perfect cadence and the basic idea is clearly brought back, I'm inclined to hear this as a (compound) period. Nowhere, as far as I could find, does Caplin mention that a antecedent may end in an evaded cadence. To be sure, he does not forbid it. Hence, the question: Can an evaded cadence end the antecedent of a period?

If that is not the case, then I believe m. 8 would bring a PAC and the beginning of a new main theme (as a transition clearly starts at m. 21, after a PAC) which would leave us with two main themes with identical basic ideas and a weak/strong cadential pattern. As single main themes are the more normative option and as I am not used to considering two themes with such similar openings and with such a cadential pattern to not be a compound period, that option feels rather uncomfortable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In measures 7-8 we have a root position dominant moving to a root position tonic in a way that sounds to me as a cadential evasion, due to sudden change in dynamics, register and texture.

Dynamics, register, texture don't determine cadences. Bass and melody determine cadences. It's a perfect cadence at m. 8. That makes sense as it emphatically establishes the tonic.

Mm. 17 to 18 there is an actual evaded cadence, or at least an evasive progression.

Generally I think an antecedent could end with any *inconclusive* cadence, any ending that isn't the tonic. That's how Caplin puts it, in relative terms of weak/strong, rather that specific chords like `V` and `I`, in his book *Classical Form.*

I don't think the opening of this movement involves periods. Caplin mentions the *"nonelision of antecedent with consequent"* There isn't a weak phrase ending - without eliding overlap - then a strong phrase ending. The movement starts with a series of sentences.

Comment: I dissagree that harmonic content alone determining cadences, and so does Caplin. As he puts in The Classical Cadence: Conceptions and Misconceptions and elsewhere: "Passages of cadential content do not always function as syntactical cadences." I am referring here to cadences as formal endings, maybe I should have made that clear in the question. If we accept that a cadence is solely determined by harmonic content, then there is no doubt that m. 8 brings a cadence.

Comment: As the V resolve to a IV (or VI, depending on how you analyze) in m. 18, I consider that to be a deceptive cadence. But yes, there is a cadential deviation there.

Comment: But I tend to agree that, more generally, an antecedent could end with any inconclusive cadence. It seems to me that the 'weak/strong' principle is more defining than the specific types of cadences involded.

Comment: _"Passages of cadential content do not always function as syntactical cadences."_ Right. And Caplin is the one who set me straight on that, but it's a different issue. My understanding, my simplified way to put the idea is this: we need the end of a phrase to mark a cadence and then classify it by it's harmony. Mm. 7 to 8 do mark the end and start of a phrase, the harmony is `V` to `I`, so its a perfect cadence, the phrases are elided so it isn't a period.

Comment: As far as I understand, the conditions you put (ending and starting a phrase, movement from V to I and elision) can also be satisfied by evaded cadences in the sense that "A cadential evasion can occur even if the cadential dominant moves to a root-position tonic, as long as there is sufficient disruption of melody, texture, dynamics, register, and so on to counter our perceiving a structural end when the I chord appears" (Analyzing Classical Form, p. 370), so they do not automatically make the situation a perfect cadence.

Comment: But I do perceive a thematic ending at m. 8, so I agree that, indeed, it is a perfect cadence at m. 8 (as far as the theory of formal functions is concerned).

Comment: I also agree with the nonelision requirement. I keep forgetting that one. Thanks!

Comment: I tend to think of forms other than sonata allegro form, those like minuet/trio, rondo, theme and variations, etc. to more commonly involve periods.